# Fourier transform with cubic exponential

Tags: integral-transforms, integral-operators

Please give references for the integral transform of the next kind:
$$
F_3(f(x))(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(Q_3(x,t)) f(t)\,dt ,
$$
with $Q_3(x,t)$ - a cubic polynomial of its arguments. Special cases are interesting, and of course a general case. It seems such transforms are used in PDO theory, not so?

Comment: Have you tried Google search?

Comment: The key word is Airy function. What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean the Airy transform?
[image]

A more recent reference is [The Airy transform and the associated polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2517) (2010).

In your notation the function $F_3$ is the Airy transform of the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of $f$:

$$F_3(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\,\exp\left(\tfrac{1}{3}it^3+itx\right)f(t)$$
$$\qquad=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\xi\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\exp\left(\tfrac{1}{3}it^3-it(\xi-x)\right)\hat{f}(\xi)$$
$$\qquad=\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\xi\, {\rm Ai}(\xi-x)\hat{f}(\xi).$$

Comment: Could you  base your words "In your notation the function $F_3$ is the Airy transform of the Fourier transform of $f$"? @Carlo Beenakker

Comment: @user64494 --- I've added the requested steps.

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakkeer: Sorry, but this is not it bacause $Ai(\xi−x)$  does not have a form $\exp(Q_3(x,t))$.

Comment: you should look at the first line: $Q_3(x,t)=\frac{1}{3}it^3+itx$

Comment: Sorry, I see $\tfrac{1}{3}it^3-it(\xi-x)$ . @Carlo Beenakker

Comment: Carlo Beenakker -thank you, that is one variant of such transform. I also remember something like "Bros-Yagolnitzer" PDO, or my memory lies to me?

Comment: I checked-Bros-Iagolnitzer PDO is with quadrics in exp, not cubic.